Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file - while run project
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\Projects\Flutter_Projects\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\abc.d.gradle\caches\7.6.3\scripts\89h1b0pgkuoa5c28iqf1kcknq).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
MY Flutter SDK is 3.22.2 & Android version 2024.2 & JDK_HOME version is 17.0.7 & Gradle version is 7.6.4

I ran into this error because I had Java 21 on Android Studio Ladybug, so I followed this thread and eventually changed my flutter config jdk directory to Java 17.
